# C++: Implicit call of constructor from another constructor

Tags: c++, oop, visual-studio-2012, copy-constructor

I'm having a hard time understanding implicit constructor calls in a project I'm working on.
 
There are two interfaces: InterfaceA and InterfaceB. 
Then, there are two implementation classes: ImplementA and ImplementB, which are derived from the respective interface. There is no mutual ancestor in any point - even though the interfaces and classes are very much alike.
A third class, Component, can be used to initialize any of the Implement classes. 
So we have something like this:

```
class InterfaceA 
{
public:
    InterfaceA(){}
    virtual ~InterfaceA(){}

    // Some functions
}

class InterfaceB 
{
public:
    InterfaceB(){}
    virtual ~InterfaceB(){}

    // Some functions
}

class ImplementA : public InterfaceA
{
public:
    ImplementA(Component& input);
    ImplementA(Component* input);
    ImplementA(const ImplementA& impl);
    ImplementA(const ImplementB& impl);
    ImplementA();
    ~ImplementA(void);

private:
    Component* m_component;
    bool some_boolean;
}

class ImplementB : public InterfaceB
{
public:
    ImplementB(Component& input);
    ImplementB(const ImplementA& impl);
    ImplementB(const ImplementB& impl);
    ImplementB();
    ~ImplementB(void);

private:
    Component* m_component;
}
```

Then, we have a function that returns a pointer to Component:

```
Component* foo()
{
    Component* result = new Component();
    ...
    return result;
}
```

And finally, somewhere in the code, we have the following return:

```
return new ImplementB(foo());
```

When run, the line above executes foo(), then executes ImplementA(Component* input), and then ImplementB(const ImplementA& impl) - which confuses me very much.
1. Why does it even compile? Shouldn't the compiler complain that there is no valid constructor for this type of argument (which it does when I change something in the call in question). I'm using Visual Studio 2012, by the way.
2. I know that when a constructor gets a pointer to an object as an argument, it first calls the copy constructor of the argument. So, if I ignore the fact that there's no fitting constructor - shouldn't it use the copy constructor of Component instead of ImplementA? ImplementA seems to have absolutely no connection to ImplementB (aside from them having a similar structure).

What am I missing? What could be causing this behavior in this situation?

Comment: Perhaps you should make your constructors `explicit` so no implicit conversions like this would be allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you get for having too many, confusing constructors. I also strongly suspect that you have memory leaks all over the place.

Note that `ImplementA` has a constructor `ImplementA(Component&)` and a constructor `ImplementA(Component*)`. But `ImplementB` has only `ImplementB(Component&)`. This is confusing.

So when you do `new ImplementB(foo())`, there's no constructor that accepts a `Component*` directly. The compiler goes looking for other options. Specifically, it goes looking for a way to convert the argument `Component*` to something that some constructor of `ImplementB` accepts.

C++ has something called user-defined conversions. You can define *conversion operators* and *converting constructors* that define new implicit type conversions between types. Here's the thing: any constructor with a single parameter is a converting constructor, unless it is marked with `explicit`. (This is probably a design mistake in C++. But we're stuck with it.)

Therefore, `ImplementA(Component*)` defines an implicit conversion from `Component*` to `ImplementA`. And there's the `ImplementB(const ImplementA&)` constructor that would accept a `ImplementA` temporary just fine. So the compiler uses this constructor, uses the converting constructor to create the temporary, and the end result is the execution you're seeing.

The solution is to make all these constructors `explicit`, and also to define fewer, less confusing constructors. And to use smart pointers to get rid of the memory leaks.

Comment: So basically, C++ will do a back flip to find a way to convert the argument to something the constructor (one of the constructors) will accept? Is there a limit on how much conversions it can do?
This is some old code - one of the reasons I'm messing with this is to get rid of memory leaks. I _wish_ I could just rewrite it.

Comment: It will allow exactly one user-defined conversion.

Comment: @A.Pet - Specifically, we have `foo()` return `Component*` -> `ImplementA` -> `ImplementB`. Since the "conversion" to `ImplementB` is explicit (the c'tor is written down in the code), we have exactly one *implicit* conversion, although we really have *two* conversions. IFF the line read `return foo()` instead, you'd have two implicit conversions and the code would fail to compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
return new ImplementB(foo());
```

> When run, the line above executes foo(), then executes ImplementA(Component* input), and then ImplementB(const ImplementA& impl) - which confuses me very much.

The call to `foo` returns a `Component*`. When we check the constructors for `ImplementB` we find

```
ImplementB(Component& input);
ImplementB(const ImplementA& impl);
ImplementB(const ImplementB& impl);
```

So none of these accepts a `Component*`.

But "luckily" one of the options is an `ImplementA` which *can* be constructed from the pointer.

And *one* "user-defined conversion" is allowed when passing a parameter.

Comment: Only one? Is this set by standard or dependent on something?

Comment: @A.Pet - Yes, the standard says at most one. The compiler should not try to find perhaps 20 steps to convert from one type to another. It would be both totally confusing for the programmer, and a lot of work for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` returns a `Component*`.

`ImplementB` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `Component*`. However it has a constructor that accepts a `const ImplementA&`.

Now `Component*` is *implicitly convertible* to `ImplementA` via the constructor of the latter that accepts a `Component*`. So it gets converted, and the resulting `ImplementA` temporary is passed by const reference to the appropriate constructor of `ImplementB`.

If you value your sanity, you probably don't want **any** implicit conversions anywhere near your code. To stop implicit conversions of user-defined types, declare all single-argument constructors `explicit`.